# DynamoDB batchGet vs multiple getItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is there any difference in terms of cost or performance between using multiple `getItem` calls:

```js
Promise.all([
     client.getItem({ TableName, Key }).promise(),
     client.getItem({ TableName, Key }).promise(),
     client.getItem({ TableName, Key }).promise(),
   ]
```

to one `batchGet` call:

```js
const params = {
  RequestItems: {
    'TABLE_NAME': {
      Keys: [
        {'KEY_NAME': {N: 'KEY_VALUE_1'}},
        {'KEY_NAME': {N: 'KEY_VALUE_2'}},
        {'KEY_NAME': {N: 'KEY_VALUE_3'}}
      ]
    }
  }
};

db.batchGetItem(params).promise()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of **cost: No** - both Operations consume the same number of Read Capacity Units.

In terms of **performance: Yes** - using multiple GetItem requests sends separate network requests for each of them and for BatchGetItem there is only one request, which should be quite a bit faster.

There is no real downside to BatchGetItem except for a slight increase in complexity when some items aren't found.